# mongodb get the list of id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the below user collection

```
{  
   "_id":"562e7c594c12942f08fe4192",
   "shape":"square",
   "color":"blue"
},
{  
   "_id":"562e7c594c12942f08fe4193",
   "shape":"square",
   "color":"black"
}
```

How can i get only the `_id` attribute with mongodb to get the list of id

With jpa the query is like below

```
@Query("SELECT u.id FROM User u)
Set<String> findUserIds();
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve this should do the trick db.collection.find({},{_id:1})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `MongoRepository`, you can write it this way:

```
@Query(value="{}", fields="{_id : 1}")
List<User> findIds();
```

This will only populate the `id` field within the user objects, which then can be mapped to a collection of strings.